# Unable to provide user input in PyDev console on Eclipse with Jython

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev, jython

I was trying to debug a jython program for a long time that I was running in Eclipse using the PyDev plugin, but it worked once I ran it from the terminal instead. I suspected it might be that the user input wasn't working on the Eclipse console, so I tried running the most basic input program for jython I could think of

```
name = raw_input("What is your name? ")
print "Hello %s" % (name)
```

When this runs it outputs

```
What is your name?
```

and when I type in the console, the normal green text appears, but upon hitting enter, nothing happens. How can I get the console to feed the input back to the process?

EDIT: The input is fed to the program upon pressing Terminate, so it outputs

```
Hello name
```

Also, this is only happening when using PyDev, input works fine when running java code in the java perspective

Answer (score 0):

This is really strange (and works for me).

So, to properly identify what's happening, I need some more info:

1. What's the jython version you're using?
2. Do you have something in your error log?
3. What's the Eclipse version?
4. How exactly are you doing the run? (hint: just pressing F9 should be enough)

Comment: 1.Jython 2.5.3 
2.Nothing in the error log, nothing happens and the input is fed back to the process upon terminating, running fine at that point 
3.Eclipse 3.8.0 
4.I am running it normally, nothing fancy, hitting the run button